How to trigger an update request only if a user changes settings in a modal (React Native Expo 52 with Redux)?
I’m working on a React Native application using Expo SDK 52. In my app, I have a modal that allows users to update certain settings. The values in the modal are managed using a Redux slice. Here's what I want to achieve:

When the modal closes, I want to check if the user has made any changes to the settings.
If any setting was changed, I want to send an update request (e.g., to an API).
If no changes were made, I want to avoid sending any request.

I’m currently facing the following challenges:

Tracking changes: How can I efficiently compare the settings state before and after the modal interaction to determine if any updates were made?
Optimized updates: What’s the best approach to implement this logic to ensure performance and avoid unnecessary requests?

Here's a simplified structure of my current implementation:

Redux slice: I use Redux to store the settings (both the original values and the updated values from the modal).
Modal logic: The modal allows users to modify settings, and I update the Redux state when inputs change.


What actually constitutes a "change" in your Redux state? What/when/how are you making API requests? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Store updated values in local state in the modal. Add a focus listener that, when the modal loses focus, compares local state to redux state. If there’s a change, fire an api call.
